# Javascript can't execute this simple code

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to toggle a navbar when you click on a button. I've followed an example but my javascript gives an error: ***caught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined
at HTMLDivElement.myFunction (script.js:6)
myFunction @ script.js:6***

The Code:

```
var myNavigation = document.getElementsByTagName("nav");

var myFunction = function (){
       if (myNavigation.style.display === "none") {
              myNavigation.style.display === "flex"
       } else {
              myNavigation.style.display === "none"
       }
};

myButton.onclick = myFunction;
```

Comment: Probably `myNavigation` is not ablel

Comment: see there you are calling `myfunction` in bad way you should it like this `myFunction()` with the brackets

Comment: the `getElementsByTagName` should return an array. You can access the elements of that array like this: `myNavigation[0].style.display = "flex";` where `[0]` accesses the first element in that array. Also note there is only one `=` not 3.

Comment: @Gad No, he's not trying to call `myFunction` there, no `()` supposed to be there.

Comment: and if also while you were selecting button you used selector that return in array you should index on it

Comment: I'm sorry @Bergi i didn't saw that is a variable

Answer (score 3):

You are using `document.getElementsByTagName()`. This returns an array. You have to target a specific element inside that array.

Answer (score 1):

[getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns a list, not an element.

Comment: It does return a *live* HTMLCollection though, so it doesn't matter what it will find at load time